# How to add an hour to a timespan. C#

Tags: c#

I have my `TimeSpan` for a specific reason so it HAS to be in that format. I'm trying to add an hour on to the current time. Here is what I got, which does not work:

```
TimeSpan time1= TimeSpan.FromHours(1); // my attempt to add 2 hours
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
ts.Add(time1);
MessageBox.Show(ts.ToString()); // for showing me its result
```

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The method `Add` of `TimeSpan` is not modifying the value of `ts`. It is summing the values and returning a new object.

So instead you should do:

```
 TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
 var ts2 = ts.Add(time1);
 MessageBox.Show(ts2.ToString());
```

Comment: Works perfect with my code. Thanks very much. My bad I understand now.

Comment: @Jeremyc Operations with `TimeSpan` and `DateTime` usually return new objects. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 38):

```
ts += TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
```

and there you have it!

Answer (score 20):

The reason why your code does not work is that `TimeSpan` is immutable. The [`TimeSpan.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add.aspx) method returns a new object:

```
ts = ts.Add(time1);
```

Comment: +1 for using the word 'immutable' as this is the important bit.

Comment: Wondering why didn't they make it `static` then?? (just saying)

Answer (score 6):

Use AddHours();

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
```

or, to use your code (see the `newTs` variable)..

```
TimeSpan time1 = TimeSpan.FromHours(1); // my attempt to add 2 hours
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
var newTs = ts.Add(time1);
MessageBox.Show(newTs.ToString());
```

Also, your comment says 'my attempt to add 2 hours', is this a typo?

Comment: why would it be a typo

Comment: @Jeremyc, you mention 2 hours, but you have 1 in the parenthesis.

Answer (score 4):

My 2 cents: The question title says - How to add an hour to a timespan. C#, only one answer is accurate to that effect. Here's my take on adding hours to a time span:

```
public static TimeSpan AddHours(TimeSpan timeSpan, int hoursToAdd)
{
   TimeSpan newSpan = new TimeSpan(0, hoursToAdd, 0, 0);
   return timeSpan.Add(newSpan);
}
```

Here's a fiddle to Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iuh66s

Answer (score 3):

```
var newDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
```

No need to create a `TimeSpan`. This will roll over to tomorrow.

Comment: I need it to be a timespan using             TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

Comment: Why? It's not clear from your question why you need it as a time span.

Comment: what if it rolls over 24 hours?

Comment: @Jeremyc you can compare datetimes.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:-

```
TimeSpan time1 = TimeSpan.FromHours(1); // my attempt to add 2 hours
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
var newts = ts.Add(time1);
MessageBox.Show(newts.ToString());
```

Try this:-

```
var newDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newTime = oldTime.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
```

Don't fall into the common mistake of not assigning the value to anything (i.e. `newTime`) as `oldTime` will remain the same - `TimeSpan.Add(...)` returns `TimeSpan`.

Same applies for `String.Replace(...)` - easy, but devastating, to miss.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to add minutes to time and if time is variable and not constant

```
TimeSpan firstTime = TimeSpan.Parse(firstTime);
TimeSpan NeededTimeForAdd= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(SessionMinutes);    
TimeSpan ExpectedTime = firstTime.Add(NeededTime);
```